# Getting the Django-generated unique name of a file uploaded multiple times

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF backend to upload files. In my specific case I will want to get the name of the file, **after** it has been uploaded. The reason is that if a user uploads a file with same name, I am still able to process it independently.

**views.py**:

```
class ImageUploaderView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer]
    queryset = ImageUploader.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageUploaderSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
```

**serializer.py**:

```
class ImageUploaderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageUploader
```

**models.py**:

```
class ImageUploader(models.Model):
    # name=models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    name=models.FileField(upload_to='media')
```

I tried to put signals and hooks after the model definitions but I am not being able to get this filename. Can someone shed some light pls?

**UPDATE:** Let me elaborate what I want to achieve essentially:

- User1 hits endpoint "/api/calculate_interest_rate" which is rendered
  by a frontend React component. "calculate_interest_rate" is served by
  DRF, and lets the user upload a CSV file. This will be stored as
  "user1.csv", the file is processed and then tabulated (rendered by
  React).
- At the same time and in parallel to User1, User2 hits the same endpoint "/api/calculate_interest_rate" and
  by mistake he saves his file as "user1.csv", and uploads it to the systemn.

So I want to be able to detect both names of the file in order to process it. By using always the same default filename (ex. using the OverwriteStorage() technique), I will probably cause chaos when two or more users are using the same filename. Therefore I am looking into a technique that allows me to get the filename as is, and process it immediately.

Comment: why not using the session? eg: `user_<session_key>.csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using storage option?

```
class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        print("filename", name)
        #parts = name.split('.') you can separate name and extension.
        return super().get_available_name(name)

upload_image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to=[yourpath],
    default=[defaultname],
    storage=OverwriteStorage()
)
```

Comment: I prefer not to overwrite. Please check my update for clarification.

Comment: I read your update. Actually, If there is same name file in your path, Django automatically put underscore and 7 random characters to prevent saving same name file. [source here, get_available_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/core/files/storage/#Storage.get_available_name). I just suggested to tweak it when you have same filename at moment you save.

Comment: Why don't you put user pk number so that filename can't be duplicated with other files?  `models.FileField(upload_to=your_custom_path)` `def your_custom_path(instance, filename): return 'user_{0}'.format(instance.user.id)` If you save your file with format like user_user's unique pk number, you don't have to worry that multiple users save same filename.

Comment: that is actually a good strategy and I think it answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to following this configuration:

**1.** Change your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` inside file of `settings.py`

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/env/projectname/media'
```

**2.** Then, I suggest you to change your `upload_to='media` to `upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d`, also rename your field of `name` with `image`.

```
class ImageUploader(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    # OR
    # image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
```

> **Explanation;** If you following this configuration, you could have uploaded images are following, eg: `/media/images/2017/01/29/yourimage.jpg`. This is one way to handle the problem of *duplicated files*.

**3.** But if you want to upload file with multiple times without duplicate files, you can using `deconstructible`;

```
import os, time, uuid
from django.db import models
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible


class ImageUploader(models.Model):

    @deconstructible
    class PathAndRename(object):

        def __init__(self, sub_path):
            self.path = sub_path

        def __call__(self, instance, filename):
            # eg: filename = 'my uploaded file.jpg'
            ext = filename.split('.')[-1]  #eg: '.jpg'
            uid = uuid.uuid4().hex[:10]    #eg: '567ae32f97'

            # eg: 'my-uploaded-file'
            new_name = '-'.join(filename.replace('.%s' % ext, '').split())

            # eg: 'my-uploaded-file_64c942aa64.jpg'
            renamed_filename = '%(new_name)s_%(uid)s.%(ext)s' % {'new_name': new_name, 'uid': uid, 'ext': ext}

            # eg: 'images/2017/01/29/my-uploaded-file_64c942aa64.jpg'
            return os.path.join(self.path, renamed_filename)

    image_path = time.strftime('images/%Y/%m/%d')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=PathAndRename(self.image_path))
```

Comment: I prefer not to overwrite. Also, consider multiple users are uploading at the same time. How can I get the filenames so I can process the correct file? Please check the updates of the thread for clarification.